# Google CDN for Angular Dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to reduce the following includes down to one?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
```

I cannot find a combined version of these hosted on Google's CDN.

Comment: +1 I have not seen one... very interested in this answer.

Comment: I know this is unrelated, but how did you find all those CDN URLs? Google's "Hosted Libraries" page doesn't seem to list anything other than the main angular library.

Comment: @twiz according to Google's Angular CDN announcement blog post, you can find non-minified and module urls for a version of angular via: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/MANIFEST (replacing the version number with your version of choice). I suppose adding this to the main site was too much trouble for them lol.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Awesome! This seems to work for all the other hosted libraries too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have been looking for a bundle myself, but haven't found one yet. Seems to me you have to bundle them manually if you want to have them all in one js. file.

---

I was thinking about creating a grunt task (or similar) to fetch all dependencies and merge them into one file. I know you want to use a CDN, but just wanted to share that thought.

*update*
For anyone interested in the latter, just came across this [grunt-fetch-from-cdn plugin](https://github.com/vijeysrc/grunt-fetch-from-cdn/). Haven't tried it myself yet, but looks interesting.

Answer (score 9):

I would argue that the main benefit of a CDN is for everyone to be using the same files, thus allowing for caching to remove the need to load the file at all for most visitors due to its widespread use across other sites.

Assumably, the number of permutations required to bundle various configurations of Angular dependencies would completely negate this benefit, and you would be better off packaging the bundle with all of your other JS for the lowest possible number of requests and serving it yourself.

However, it does seem as if Angular updates rather frequently which, while good for bug fixes, means that there are probably many different versions (and thus files) in use in production environments at the moment. This will also lower the benefit of caching across various sites.

When in doubt, test both methods across devices from friends/family/work/etc. that have seen normal internet usage on sites other than your own.

I would guess that in most cases it would be smarter to just include each module's CDN link separately like you did above and let caching take care of reducing the actual number of requests. If that becomes common practice then the extra number of files won't have much impact on load time.

Comment: This is one of the best analyses I've found on the benefit of sharing CDNs: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/03/18/http-archive-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Colt, but the following can be useful if used wisely (see "Load multiple files with a single HTTP request"): [JSDelivr](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/03/jsdelivr-the-advanced-open-source-public-cdn/)

Answer (score 2):

Either you can use **gulp task** to build them up into a single script or you can use **bower** to install these dependencies at once.